# Using grepl to create multiple data frames based on string input in R

Tags: r, split, subset, gsub, grepl

I'm trying to split 1 dataframe in 16 dataframes using grepl given a string input. It's a very simple dataset consisting of 2400 variables I'm using in my research (excluding the actual observations at this point). So one column, with 2400 observations (the variables) of type string.

This is to identify which variables are used at each measurement moment. Each measurement moment is denoted by specific string in the name of the variable (i.e. "_H1", "_H2", "_H2_1", etc.).

Currently I'm using this:

```
df <- read_csv("~/SRP/R/variables.csv", col_names = FALSE)

# Subsetting part of df by seperating input "_H2" and later "_H2_1"
df.H2 <- as.data.frame(subset(df, grepl("_H2", df$X1)))
df.H2.1 <- as.data.frame(subset(df.H2, grepl("_H2_1$", df.H2$X1)))

# Removing _H2_1 from the df to be able to compare on variables
df.H2.1 <- as.data.frame(gsub("_H2_1", "", df.H2.1$X1))

# Change the column name
colnames(df.H2.1) <- "Variables"
```

This seems terribly inefficient. Is there a way to combine this into one function? Rather than having to do this 16 times.

edit: This is what I have now: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybqNz.png) (each observation is a variable). The aim of what I'm doing is getting a feel for which variables are in each measurement moment and whether or not I can compare them to each other. Receiving a list of all dataframes based on what is in them is something I would aim for (similar to what happens with a bind_rows function, which didn't work for me).

dput of small sample:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("MMSE_natekenen_file_H3", "CCI_H1.HIVpositief_Score_6", "score_chair_sit_and_reach_H2_9", "SPPB_score_test3_H2_4", "IMP5_BIA_H2_7", "commando_H3.Papier_in_rechterhand_nemen","SNAQ_3_P2","DEMMI_7_H2_6","Monocyten_medisch_dossier_H1_2","FAT_BIA_H2_7","SW_BIA_H2_6","vision_P3","DEMMI_8_H2_9","shortness_of_breath_H2_8","GDS_2_P3")), .Names = "X1", row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try something like `split(df, sub(".*_(H.+)$", "\\1", df$X1))`

Comment: Can you `dput` your data? If I understand you correctly and you are are trying to split your data frame into 16 data frames given your variable names, you could reshape your data to long format (e.g. via dplyr's `gather` function) and split that data frame along the lines of the newly generated long variable (e.g. via dplyrs `split` function). This will give you a list of data frames which you can pull into your environment as objects via `list2env(yourlist,envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: somple sample data (few obs.) along with what you expect to see in the final data.frame would be useful. From what I understood so far, you may be able to `grep` the `colnames` and subset those using `lapply` to get a list in a single step.

Comment: I have added new information to the post. Please let me know if there is anything else I can add.